# External function not working on page load, but working on button press

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, ejs

I have an EJS template where I am using an external function in 2 different ways. When the document loads, I want to loop through existing data, and on button click I want to fire the function as well. Its working well on click, but not working when page loads.

The external JS function inserts a form for clients to declare their debts. The users have already declared their debts. I'm working on the edit page where they can change previous information or declare new debts.

When the page loads I want to:

A) loop through their existing debts, feed the information into the addDebt function and create a prepopulated form on the fly.

B) I also want them to be able to add new debts with the dropdown button that use the same function to insert a blank form.

B works perfectly, but the function isn't recognised in A. I'm sure this is a timing issue, with the DOM content not having been loaded when NODE tries to render A. I just can't figure out how to fix it. When I try adding window.onload to function.js it stops working altogether!

Sorry if this question is verbose or unclear, as my username suggests I'm new to this.

```
function.js 

function  addDebt(x, y) {

  DOM manipulation to insert different form elements based on value of x (ie “credit card”, 
   “home Loan” etc)


  if (y == '1')   
   generate pre populated fields for existing debts




Ejs

<div class="container main">
    <h4>Edit debts:</h4>

//PART A - loop through existing debts of the user and feed them into the 
function to generate pre populated forms for editing the information

<%  liabilities.forEach(function(liability){ %> 
    addDebt(<%=  liability.type %>, ‘1’);
    <% }); %>       


// PART B - allow user to add new debts by selecting them from dropdown     

   <div class="dropdown col-12 col-sm-3 mb-2">
       <button  data-toggle="dropdown">
        Add a new debt 
       </button>
   <div class="dropdown-menu">
       <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="addDebt('Home Mortgage', '0')" 
          href="#">Mortgage on your home</a>

       <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="addDebt('Credit Card, '0',     
         '0')"href="#">Credit cards</a>

       <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="addDebt('Car Loan', '0')" 
        href="#">Car Loans</a>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I am not sure that i understand you good, but put all your javascript code at the bottom of your <body> tag. That's always good practice, to be sure document is loaded before script is executed

Comment: Code in EJS templates runs on the server. `function.js` doesn't really exist at that point. You can either a) write EJS code that inserts the form elements or b) pass all `liabilities` to the client-side, then let the browser pre-populate your document.

Comment: @Deathmras, thanks for the suggestion.  I tried it, but the function is still not recognised. I need it in a separate file as it is used by multiple pages and is very long.

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks. I figured as much. But in that case if I include the function as a script at the bottom of the ejs page as suggested by Deathmras above it should work, but didn't.

Comment: It shouldn't work, and won't. You cannot call `document.createElement()` and the like on the server, period. There *is* no `document` yet, no DOM to manipulate yet. That will only exist after the EJS view engine has rendered HTML, node has sent that HTML to the browser and the browser has parsed it into a DOM. If you have tons of code in function.js, the best course is to request `liabilities` via `fetch()` in the browser so it is available client-side, then run an `addDebt()` loop.

Comment: What is the error in your console?

Comment: figured it out, just had to run the function via   '<body onload="addDebt()">'

Thanks to everyone for the help.